# SQL combine weekend dates to one total

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to combine weekend dates by using datename.

TABLE

- DATE
- 11/25/2018
- 11/24/2018
- 11/25/2018

So I use DATENAME and convert the dates to the day of the week.

- DATE
- Sunday
- Saturday
- Sunday

Then I can count them to get it to look like this

- DATE . COUNT
- Sunday . 2
- Saturday . 1

But Im unsure how to group these so it looks like

- DATE . COUNT
- WEEKEND . 3

Comment: Probably best to do a select where you gather all dates where DATE=='Sunday' OR DATE=='Saturday' and then just sum over that and output it as a table with one entry

Comment: You can use select query to select what you have as inner query to get the result.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a couple of ways you can do it.  You will notice the `COUNT` version you have to return NULL so the `COUNT()` function won't count it.  You can also use `SUM()`.  There are other ways to do it as well.

```
DECLARE @x TABLE (mydate DATE);

INSERT INTO @x SELECT '11-25-2018'; --Sunday
INSERT INTO @x SELECT '11-24-2018'; --Saturday
INSERT INTO @x SELECT '11-25-2018'; --Sunday
INSERT INTO @x SELECT '11-23-2018'; --Friday

SELECT count(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, mydate) BETWEEN 2 and 6 THEN NULL ELSE 1 END ) AS CountOfWeekendDays
    ,sum(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, mydate) BETWEEN 2 and 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfWeekDays
    ,sum(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, mydate) BETWEEN 2 and 6 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS SumOfWeekendDays
FROM @x
```

Comment: What it we have `SET DATEFIRST 1 -- MONDAY`? 2 and 6 then must be changed to 6 and 7.

Answer (score 1):

You would group by the datename(weekday,) to get you the necessary output.

```
create table t(date_of_hire date);

insert into t values('2018-11-25');
insert into t values('2018-11-24');
insert into t values('2018-11-25');

select datename(weekday,date_of_hire) as day_of_week,count(*) as cnt
  from t
  group by datename(weekday,date_of_hire)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the total weekend days

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as totalweekdays FROM tablename 
WHERE 
DATENAME(weekday, datecolumn) = 'Saturday'   
OR
DATENAME(weekday, datecolumn) = 'Sunday'
```